# spresnense config.pyにてモジュール化？ができない。

Tags: spresense

spresenseで2~3プロジェクトをconfig.pyにてmodulazes？したいのですが、Mキーが押せず、できない状態です。
「Y」キーで必要なプロジェクトを有効化するとコンパイルエラーになります。
また、spresense始めたばかりで認識不足のことが多いため、間違っていたりすれば、ぜひご指摘くださいませ。
よろしくお願いいたします。

make.def等覗いてみましたが、プロジェクトの中でまとめてコンパイルすることまではできました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「M」キーが押せないというのは、アプリケーションをローダブルELFにしたいということかなと思います。

ローダブルELFについては、こちらのチュートリアルが参考になると思います。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_ローダブルelfチュートリアル](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%96%E3%83%ABelf%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB)

手順としては、アプリのKconfigを`tristate`にしておく

```
config EXAMPLES_XXX
    tristate "XXX example"
    default n
```

そして`feature/loadble`を有効にした状態で、`menuconfig`を開くと、
`tristate`を設定したCONFIGに関して「Y」「M」「N」から選択できるようになります。

```
$ ./tools/config.py feature/loadble
$ ./tools/config.py -m
```

P.S.
「Y」キーで必要なプロジェクトを有効化するとコンパイルエラーになるということなので、
これは「M」キーでモジュールに変えても同じくコンパイルエラーになるような気がします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事にモジュールに変えることができました。が、おっしゃるとおり、コンパイルエラーがでました。もし、解説いただければとても助かります。
LD: nuttx
arm-none-eabi-ld: /home/hoge/spresense/nuttx/staging/libapps.a(symtab_apps.o):(.rodata.g_exports+0x2cc): undefined reference to `system'
Makefile:155: recipe for target 'nuttx' failed
make[2]: *** [nuttx] Error 1
make[2]: ディレクトリ '/home/hoge/spresense/nuttx/arch/arm/src' から出ます
tools/Makefile.unix:420: recipe for target 'nuttx' failed
make[1]: *** [nuttx] Error 2
make[1]: ディレクトリ '/home/hoge/spresense/nuttx' から出ます
Makefile:113: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
エラー内容になります。